# Is this a photo of Trump's inauguration crowd?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

[Metro.us](http://www.metro.us/news/trump-will-hang-inauguration-crowd-photo-in-white-house-press-room/zsJqax---Eholf568ekMJs/) claims:

> Tuesday afternoon, Trump tweeted a photo of a framed image of the crowds at his inauguration, adding that he plans to hang the picture in the White House press hall.

[image: Trump's picture]

The date printed on the picture seems incorrect, however is it a genuine photo of the crowds at his inauguration?

Comment: @bobthefunny i've refocused the question on the notable (newspaper) claim and not on what Trump meant with that tweet; secondly I've removed the false dilemma from the post: either the photo is genuine or it isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can compare the photo with other photos of the inauguration such as [CNN's gigapixel](http://www.cnn.com/interactive/2017/01/politics/trump-inauguration-gigapixel/) or [this photo](http://i0.wp.com/www.powerlineblog.com/ed-assets/2017/01/C2vkyVAUAAAU2Zb.jpg-large.jpeg). We then can note several similarities between the photos, such as the position of crowds and bleachers, the large lights, the flags, ect. Given the similarities between the photos, I think it does appear to be a photo taken during the inauguration with an incorrect date on it.